# How to install and use xampp

Tags: software-installation, xampp

In my downloads I have `xampp-linux-x64-7.1.7-o-installer.run`, but when I click it it tries to run and then throws an error saying I need to become a super user as root privileges are required.  I tried typing `sudo` in the terminal and then dragging it into the terminal, same results. Can you help me use this app?

Answer (score 0):

It is neither wise not advisable to install xampp on Ubuntu or any Linux distribution for that matter. Follow the instructions here http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-install-lamp-on-ubuntu to install the LAMP stack. 
About permissions on Linux you need to supply the OS with a super user password (thinks Administrator from Windows but much more powerful). This is a security measure to ensure that only trusted software is installed.

Answer (score 0):

If Xampp does not work on your computer you can setup your own web developpment environement by issuing on a terminal the following command (you can add or remove packages as you need):

```
sudo apt install php5 apache2 php5-mysql mysql-server
```

This will install a web server on the computer plus a database server (mysql). If you prefer Sqlite you can install the `php5-sqlite3` package instead of the `php5-mysql`and the `mysql-server` package.

If you are running Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial) or older, replace `php5` with `php7.0` (php 5.0 is not available any more on official repositories since `php7.0` was released.

`apache2` is the webserver.

Please note that this server will run on the background of your computer, and this could provoke performance issues on old hardware...